# Detect server status in network

Tags: 12.04, networking

I want a script (python / shell) to detect machine status (up / down) in a local network.

```
UP == you can ping machine
DOWN == Cannot ping
```

I am completely newbie here.Your kind help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check for live hosts.
 Here is an example :

```
 #!/bin/bash


for ip in 192.168.1.{0..10}; 
do ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo 'Host : ' "${ip} is up"; done





nmap -sP -n -oG - 192.168.1.0-200 | grep "Up" | awk '{print $2}' |
while read line;
do echo ' Host :' $line 'is UP'; 
done


for host in $(nmap -sP -n -oG - 192.168.1.0-200 | grep "Up" | awk '{print $2}')  
do echo ' Host :' $host 'is UP'; 
done
```

I hope it helps you...
 Regards.